# How to add Array Of Objects

Tags: java, oop

How can I Manager class to add an array of Employee objects to the manager class, and create methods to add and remove employees from the Manager

EmployeeTest.java

```
package com.example;
import com.example.domain.Employee;
import com.example.domain.Engineer;
import com.example.domain.Manager;
import com.example.domain.Admin;
import com.example.domain.Director;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class EmployeeTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create the classes as per the practice
    Engineer eng = new Engineer(101, "Jane Smith", "012-34-5678", 120_345.27);

    Manager mgr = new Manager(207, "Barbara Johnson", "054-12-2367", 109_501.36, "US Marketing");

    Admin adm = new Admin(304, "Bill Munroe", "108-23-6509", 75_002.34);

    Director dir = new Director(12, "Susan Wheeler", "099-45-2340", 120_567.36, "Global Marketing", 1_000_000.00);

    // Print information about the objects you created
    printEmployee(eng);
    printEmployee(adm);
    printEmployee(mgr);
    printEmployee(mgr1);
    printEmployee(dir);

    System.out.println("\nTesting raiseSalary and setName on Manager:");
    mgr.setName ("Barbara Johnson-Smythe");
    mgr.raiseSalary(10_000.00);
    printEmployee(mgr);

}

public static void printEmployee(Employee emp) {
    System.out.println(); // Print a blank line as a separator
    // Print out the data in this Employee object
    System.out.println("Employee id:         " + emp.getEmpId());
    System.out.println("Employee name:       " + emp.getName());
    System.out.println("Employee Soc Sec #:  " + emp.getSsn());
    System.out.println("Employee salary:     " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((double) emp.getSalary()));
}
```

}

How can I edit according to the given question

Manager.java

```
package com.example.domain;

public class Manager extends Employee {
private String deptName;

public Manager(int empId, String name, String ssn, double salary, String deptName) {
    super(empId, name, ssn, salary);
    this.deptName = deptName;
}

public String getDeptName() {
    return deptName;
}
```

}

Comment: Totally unclear and voting to close.

Comment: use java.util.List study https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

You can just add an array as follows:

```
public class Manager extends Employee {
    private String deptName;
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public void addEmployee(Employee someone){
         employees.add(someone);
    }
```

and then in your main code, just add them.

```
 manager.addEmployee(someone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using an ArrayList instead of an Array. ArrayLists are good for situations like this, as they are dynamic (you don't have to set a specific size) and they have built in functions for adding and removing without having to shift all of the existing employees up or down the line.

```
package com.example.domain;

public class Manager extends Employee {
private String deptName;

ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

public Manager(int empId, String name, String ssn, double salary, String deptName) {
super(empId, name, ssn, salary);
this.deptName = deptName;
}

public String getDeptName() {
return deptName;
}

public void add(Employee e) {
employees.add(e);

}
public void remove(Employee e) {
employees.remove(e);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your manager class. You could create an ArrayList to store of type Employee and use code such as below to remove it. Alternatively from an int to remove it you could use the ID, Name, or other variations. Hopefully this is somewhat helpful to you or can get you going in the right direction.

```
`    public void removeEmployee(Employee emp, int position) {
        this.empArray.remove(position);
        System.out.println("Employee was deleted.");
    }`

   public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {
            this.empArray.add(emp);
            System.out.println("Employee was Added.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ArrayList to have the list of Employee object. And it is good practice to have the null check before add an object to the list.

```
package com.test;
```

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Manager extends Employee {

```
private String deptName;

private List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

public Manager(int empId, String name, String ssn, double salary,
        String deptName) {
    super(empId, name, ssn, salary);
    this.deptName = deptName;
}

public String getDeptName() {
    return deptName;
}

public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
    if (employee != null) {
        empList.add(employee);
    }
}

public boolean removeEmployee(Employee employee) {
    return empList.remove(employee);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use arrayList of Employees

```
ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

empolyees.add(employee);
```